# Firefox issue - if I scroll and then resize window, images disappear

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, scroll

I have a page I am designing that is purely html with a css stylesheet.
I have it set up with scrollable content with a header and footer somewhat like this example here: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/basics2.html
except my header and footer consist of multiple images as opposed to text.

The issue I am having is that when I scroll down the page a little and resize the window to a smaller size, my header and footer disappear... but only in Firefox.
When I maximize the window again, the footer appears but some 300-400-odd pixels too high and the header is still gone.
Safari, Opera and Chrome all work fine; I can resize the browser window however much I want and my page reacts appropriately.

What could be causing this?
The weird thing is that if I don't scroll at all, and then proceed to resize the window, Firefox retains my page's styling...
possibly an overflow:scroll issue?

thanks everyone

sorry, i forgot to include my link:
http://www.theskycaptain.com/THESKYCAPTAIN.COM/projects/cosmicwomb.html

(I realize that the bandcamp player isn't behaving properly and my codes a bit messy, but I'm in the midst of developing, I've just hosted it to sort out this issue: simply scroll down a bit, resize the window and then maximize and you will see what I mean)

Comment: we can not read your mind, please provide a jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving top and bottom values to your absolutely positioned elements.

i.e.

```
.topspace, .headercon, .scroller { top: 0px; }
.footer { bottom: 0px; }
```

<sup>( These are not necessarily the exact values you'd want, but simply an example )</sup>

Comment: thank you, this has fixed the issue. i am surprised that firefox has such a hard time with this, but I am glad because now my code is a bit stronger :) still some kinks to work out but off to a solid start

Answer (score 2):

Your webpage has an improperly defined `img` and `br` tags [**everywhere**](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theskycaptain.com%2FTHESKYCAPTAIN.COM%2Fprojects%2Fcosmicwomb.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) including other errors that need to be cleaned up.

Incorrect Example:

```
<img src="../image/topspace.png"></img>
```

Correct Example:

```
<img src="../image/topspace.png" alt="image" />
```

For more info on img tags, read [**here**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img).

Also, change:

```
</br>
```

To:

```
<br />
```

Comment: thank you, i am new to this and need to make sure my coding basics are correct. identifying these oversights helps a lot!